# Does XML::LibXML::Node replaceNode() replace Perl instances of the replaced node

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

... so after I replace `a` with `b`, all previous references to `a` now point to `b`?

Comment: TITS = Try It To See!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(string => '<r><p><c/></p></r>');
my ($n1) = $dom->findnodes('/r/p/c');
my ($n2) = $dom->findnodes('/r/p/c');
$n1->replaceNode('XML::LibXML::Element'->new('n'));
print $dom;
print $n1, $n2;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<r><p><n/></p></r>
<c/><c/>
```

Comment: Why do you have quotes around your package names?

Comment: @simbabque: Because http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=980498 and `::->` is too ugly to type.

Comment: @simbabque, They're protecting themselves against the remote possibility that there's a sub called `XML::LibXML`. Perl actually allows you to do use `XML::LibXML::` to solve that problem.